# Elasticsearch path.data

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two webservers, each with their own installation of Elasticsearch. 
Both these webservers have a shared folder on their D: drive.

I want to use the same data folder so that I have one set of indexes and each elasticsearch install uses those same indexes, rather than having 2 sets, one on each server.

Therefore I have changed the 'path.data' location in both elasticsearch.yml files to point to the same shared folder.

Problem is, only one webserver is able to retrieve data for queries, the other server just returns nothing when running a search query.

Am I missing a config setting?

Answer (score 0):

Are the two Elasticsearch Nodes in the same cluster ?

Each node writes to its own folder even though they share the same base directory.
As it is, seems you have two distinct Elasticsearch instances holding separate data.

Define a cluster and add the two nodes to the cluster which is the proper way to have the same data managed by multiple nodes

Answer (score 0):

bellow config works fine

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: production
  labels:
    name: production
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-data-prod
  namespace: production
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-data-prod
  namespace: production
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
---
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: data-es
  namespace: production
spec:
  version: 8.4.3
  nodeSets:
    - name: default
      count: 1
      config:
        node.store.allow_mmap: false
      podTemplate:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: elasticsearch
              # resources:
              #   limits:
              #     memory: 2Gi
              #     cpu: 2
              # env:
              #   - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
              #     value: "-Xms2g -Xmx4g"
              volumeMounts:
                - name: elasticsearch-data-prod
                  mountPath: /usr/share/production/elasticsearch/data
      volumeClaimTemplates:
        - metadata:
            name: elasticsearch-data-prod
          spec:
            accessModes:
              - ReadWriteOnce
            storageClassName: standard
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 10Gi

---
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: data-kibana
  namespace: production
spec:
  version: 8.4.3
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: data-es
```